# Status window that's always on top with AppleScript

Tags: macos, window, applescript

I have a script that automates interaction with another program with a window that takes up the whole screen.

I need to create a window that is always on top that I can print lines of text to so that my script can continuously give me status updates.

A window like the UIElementInspector that I could print to would be perfect.

Running OS X Yosemite 10.10.2

Comment: Can you provide some minimally reproducible code?

Comment: Consider using the `display notification` command (10.9+) if messages aren't too large or frequent.

Comment: They're pretty frequent, I have an infinite loop with debugging output at every iteration.

When I'm finished with the first part of this project I'll research how to create my own dialog for the output.

Thanks for the tip though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least you can write to the console log, and have the console.log window set to display on top, whenever contents changes, maybe you can tweak the formatting of your output, and the display of the console window, into something nice looking. At least there was a free standing app, that could display a console window, at front, that was a long time ago, but google it by all means. here is a handler you can use to send log statments to the Console.app, then you make a new window with it, (you select the log file from the sidebar), then you select the choice that makes it display on top, from Console.app's window menu. It is a primitive solution, but I hope it helps you, you may of course remove stuff from the handler too, if that helps you. The date command is documented in **man date**, and the formatting are documented in **man -s3 strftime**, (both shown in a Terminal window).

```
to logit(log_string, log_file)
    do shell script ¬
        "echo `date '+%Y-%m-%d %T: '`\"" & log_string & ¬
        "\" >> $HOME/Library/Logs/" & log_file & ".log"
end logit
```